# How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in android?

Tags: java, android, jar, jackson, noclassdeffounderror

I included import.io jar into my android project, tried to run example and got the following:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.importio.api.clientlite.json.JacksonJsonImplementation$1
            at com.importio.api.clientlite.json.JacksonJsonImplementation.<init>(JacksonJsonImplementation.java:17)
            at com.importio.api.clientlite.ImportIO.connect(ImportIO.java:235)
            at com.gomel.data.ImportIOTest.showandgetData(ImportIOTest.java:33)
            at com.gomel.activities.DetailedArticleActivity$1.onClick(DetailedArticleActivity.java:40)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4247)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17733)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I did google and decided that something wrong with jackson library, I had added it, but nothing changed. There is a lot of different solutions about this error here, but I cant resolve it in my case. Could you give me some advice, please?

I use Android Studio with Android SDK Tools v22.3
Also I have tried to run this project in eclipse (with jar obviously) and got the same error.

**UPD**

My build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    } }

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile files('lib/com.importio.api.clientlite-1.0.2.jar')
    compile files('lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.12.jar') }
```

[image]

I added it like a file dependencies, think it is the right option. Also there is no compile error while I don't use this methods. And of course this jars are in the `lib` folder.

Comment: Can you share your project's settings and how you imported the jar into your module. Are you using Gradle? If so share the gradle build file.

Comment: @AssafG. Yes, I use Gradle, and I just have added a picture with settings. Do you know what is going wrong?

Comment: @Ashish seems to have solved your problem, so I there is no reason to add to that. Good luck.

Comment: @AssafG. Nope. My problem is not solved yet.

Comment: Have you added the jar to your dependencies in Android Studio?

Comment: @AssafG. Yes, that is what last picture about. In my opinion, it seems to be ok.

Comment: Can you please run gradle clean and then rebuild the project?

Comment: @AssafG. I have already tried and nothing changed. I am thinking about creating a new project just to test jar importing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've got the solution.
In my case it required `jackson-all-1.9.11.jar`

This jar includes **all**  others Jackson jars (core, mapper, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Required jar `jackson-core-asl-1.9.12.jar` is missing So you have to [download](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.12) the jar and then set your `classpath`.

Comment: Sorry for dump question, but how can I do it with Android studio and Windows 7?
Please, share how did you know library version?

Comment: Nope yet. I am trying right now to follow your instructions. Could you tell me please how to set classpath ?

Comment: wait for minute i will send you steps to set classpath

Comment: dwnld jar file..right click on project name in eclipse..properties...java build path..libraries tab...add external JARs...then browse downloaded jar file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46910/discussion-between-pavelartlover-and-ashish)

Comment: my using ADT(Android development tool) in that this java built path is there

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are using ADT version 17. If yes, see if the link below helps:

http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17

Comment: I use Android Studio and Android SDK tools version is 22.3

Comment: Can you add screenshots of your eclipse library sequence for your project?